# Urdu words in PHP not printing expected

Tags: php, urdu

Not printing the expected result;

```
<?php
  mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8');
  $term="لاہوری";     
  $sel="لا";                 
  $sterm=mb_strrichr($term, $sel, true, 'utf-8');
  $prefix=mb_strrichr($term, $sel, false, 'utf-8');

  echo $sterm;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $prefix;
?>
```

**Actual Result:** لاہوری,

**Expected Result:** ہوری

**Expected Result1:** لا

Answer (score 0):

Here you have assigned "لاہوری" in `$term` and "لا" in `$sel`. 
This is stored in as  "ی روہال" (without spaces) and "ال".
So here `echo $sterm;` gives `null` as there is no characters from the beginning to the first occurrence of "ال" and  `echo $prefix;` gives the output of characters from the first occurrence of "ال" to the end, that is "ی روہال"
(لاہوری)

Answer (score -3):

```
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8');
                  $term="لاہوری";     
                  $sel="لا";                 

                  $prefix=str_replace('لا','',$term);

echo "Actual:".$term;
echo "<br>";
echo "Expected:".$prefix;
```

Comment: Thanku for your help but I want the functionality of strstr

Comment: You are trying to create an output instead of a proper solution.